# How can I pull a Docker image in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a very simple system consisting of two containers, and I can successfully orchestrate them on my local machine with docker compose.  I would like to put this system in a single VM in the cloud and allow others to easily do the same.

Because my preferred cloud provider provides easy access to a container OS, I would like to fit this system in a single container for easy distribution and deployment.  I don't think I'm doing anything to violate the difficulties [here](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/), so I was hoping to use a Docker-in-Docker setup and make a single composite image that runs docker compose to bring up my two containers, just like on my local machine.

But, when I try to add

```
RUN docker pull my/image1
RUN docker pull my/image2
```

to the composite Dockerfile that extends [the Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/), those commands fail upon build because the Docker daemon is not running.

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to pull the two sub-images into my composite image at build time to minimize startup time of the composite image.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this, but it is probably a bad idea.

1. Use docker-machine to create a docker-machine instance.
2. Use docker-machine env to get the credentials for your newly created docker-machine instance.  These will be a couple of environment variables.
3. Add something like `ARG DOCKER_HOST="tcp://172.16.62.130:2376"` for each of the credentials created in the previous step.  Put it in your Dockerfile before the first `RUN docker ...`.
4. After the last `ARG ..` but before the first `RUN docker ...` put in some `ENV DOCKER_HOST=${DOCKER_HOST}` for all credential variables.

This should enable the docker pull to work, but it does not really solve your problem because the pull happens on the docker-machine and does not get captured in the docker image.

To get your desired effect you would need to additionally have
`RUN docker save ...` to export the pulled image to a tar archive  file on the image.

Then you would have to add corresponding logic to `docker load ...` import the tar archive file.

The bottom line is that you can do this, but you probably should not.  I don't think it will save you any time.  It will probably cost you time.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your answer.  For instance, where would I add corresponding logic to "docker load"?  It can't be in the Dockerimage because that begs the original question.

Comment: Probably you would put it in the entrypoint.  This would guarantee that all necessary images are available locally - even if the internet were cut.